# What HID device information is returned in LParam when a device is reported by the system?

Tags: c++, winapi, hid

I have been searching for information on this for about 30mins now and got nothing so far. Does anyone know what HID information is buried within LParam that's returned when the system (in this case windows) reports a system device change? (either removal or arrival)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the accepted answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249673/how-to-detect-when-a-device-is-added-to-the-system), I went to the very first link which says:

> Any application with a top-level window can receive basic notifications by processing the [WM_DEVICECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480(VS.85).aspx) message.

Then I clicked on WM_DEVICECHANGE which brought me to another page that says:

> lParam
>
> > A pointer to a structure that contains event-specific data. Its format depends on the value of the wParam parameter. For more information, refer to the documentation for each event.

Each of the events is linked in the wParam description on this same page.

I hope that describing these steps will help you in future searches.